# Failed to clone template from nuxt/starter#v3. Please check the repo is valid and that you have installed git correctly

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

While creating new nuxt project using following command

**npx nuxi init nuxt-app**

Failed to clone template from nuxt/starter#v3. Please check the repo is valid and that you have installed git correctly.

[image]

Comment: Related to this: https://github.com/nuxt/framework/discussions/2113

Answer (score 1):

check git installed locally using following command

git --version

its not installed in my case

then i installed git-scm from follwing link https://github.com/git-guides/install-git

now its working fine

[image]